# Cars 101: How is torque conveyed from transmission to differential?

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission, differential

This is a very basic question. I understand that the torque is passed from the engine onto the transmission via the flywheel in manual transmission or flexplate in case of automatic. The transmission converts the input torque to an gear who size corresponds to the current vehicle movement.  What I do not understand is how the processed torque output of the transmission gets passed onto the differential, which I understand is the ultimate conveyor of power to the wheels.

Please correct any possibly incorrect assumptions above.

Comment: There's a shaft with a universal joint.... hold please

Comment: in the case of my Tacoma., i see that shaft only going to the rear wheels, not the front differential.

Comment: Then it is rear wheeled drive.

Comment: it's front wheel drive with 4WD optional

Comment: There's a box.... grr what's it's name. Basically there's this box and it has 2 rubber bands in it (proper rubber not like desk rubber bands) with like a thick part and a thin part. They transmit power down.... hold again please.

Comment: TRANSFER BOX! (see edit)

Comment: downvote, really ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This system is called the drive train:
[image]
The shaft I was talking about was the prop-shaft. How I forgot that I don't know.

If your car is allwheel drive or can be it'll have something called (unimaginatively and again, I don't know how I forgot this) a 'transfer box'

Comment: The image you show is a very *atypical* drive train. Most vehicles *do not have* a transfer case. Even most vehicles *with* a transfer case are not setup this way. A very *stange* setup to say the least. And now I think I know why, this is originally from a Russian (or other Slavic) speaking country. That's why it's Bass Ackawards.

Comment: @Paulster2 it was the first image on the search I did. I am happy to find another but the thing is even on other cars, it will not vary _too much_

Comment: It's not a huge issue. It's just when *a picture tells a thousand words*, you don't want the words your image is telling to be the wrong ones.